# Phantom SSRS Subscription

Tags: reporting-services

Last week I wrote a query to see if we had any "My Reports" subscriptions, and because nothing came up and I was concerned that I might be missing something, I created a test daily subscription to a report in my own "My Reports" folder.  The subscription was created with an invalid email address.  I get a daily report of subscription failures, and this test subscription is now showing up in this report.

The problem is that I cannot find this subscription via the report manager interface (I would like to delete it now).  Since it shows up on the daily failure report with path details, I know that I should see it under the Subscriptions report that is found in the "My Reports" folder, but it isn't showing.  I even tried going the roundabout way from Home > Users Folders > MyDomainAndUserName > My Reports > Subscriptions (and then to Manage/Subscriptions).  There is nothing there.

Would this be a permissions issue?  I have no problem seeing, creating and modifying other subscriptions.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you on?

Comment: 2014.  I am wondering if I could simply delete the line in the Subscriptions table in the db that contains the subscription:  `delete from subscriptions
where subscriptionID = 'xyz'`

Comment: Yes, you can do that. That's where it lives.

Comment: When you open the Report Manager portal, do you see a My Subscriptions link in the upper right hand corner? If so, do you see this subscription in the list there?

Comment: @Lucky - thanks, I will try that.  Didn't want to go in and potentially break something without a second opinion...

Comment: @R. Richards: yes, and there is nothing in "My Subscriptions".  That's weird.  I know that I have other subscriptions, which I *can* see when I go to manage those reports.

Comment: Yeah I've done it and there are no references anywhere else so you won't get a ghost subscription... at least any worse than you already have!

Comment: Well, it's not allowing the deletion...`The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_delete_job'`......  This report server is part of a vendor product so I'm guessing it's about permissions. Thanks very much for all your insight.